# Xcode6 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode6

Using Xcode6-Beta, I'm unable to compile code to run on the my iOS7.1 device. I get errors like this:

```
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/johnboiles/Programming/iOS/Playground-ios/Playground-ios/AppDelegate.h:9: fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
In file included from /Users/johnboiles/Programming/iOS/Playground-ios/Playground-ios/AppDelegate.m:9:
/Users/johnboiles/Programming/iOS/Playground-ios/Playground-ios/AppDelegate.h:9:9: fatal error: could not build module 'UIKit'
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
```

Interestingly `Foundation.framework` is in fact NOT in `/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks` like it was in previous versions of Xcode. I haven't (knowinglyly at least) modified anything in the SDKs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing and reinstalling Xcode6-Beta fixed the issue.

If anyone has any insight into what happened to Foundation.framework, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Xcode can be a bit flakey sometimes, specially beta versions. I had some AV classes disappearing for no reason.

Comment: Crazy. Hard to imagine what's happening there

Comment: Not sure if it's related - but it all when wrong after I ran this google script google-api-objectivec-client-master/Examples/CalendarSample/buildStripHeaders

Answer (score 1):

`Product->Clean` did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I did the following steps and everything went back to normal.

1. Reinstall the current Xcode
2. At the Xcode's first launch, `Shift + Command + K` to clean the previous build
3. Wait until the indexing done.
4. Build again.